# Error in WordPress affecting site editing

Tags: wordpress, extension, error

When I try to edit pages in my WordPress site, I get a message on the editing page: The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

The email I receive about the error states:

## Error Details

An error of type E_PARSE was caused in line 1 of the file /home/susquehanna/ssorchestra.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code. Error message: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '('

If I deactivate CiviCRM, I can edit my site like normal, if it's activated, I get the error messages. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SE!  What version of php are you using?  Sounds like you might need to switch to php 7.

Comment: Hi, I just upgraded to the latest version about a week ago

Comment: sorry, forgot the version - it's PHP 7.2

Comment: Follow-up - what version of CiviCRM are you using?  Aidan is definitely right, this is a PHP mismatch issue - but usually we see people using old versions of PHP with new versions of CiviCRM.  You might have the "opposite" problem.

Comment: Also, check that your webserver is actually using php7.2 - webserver and command-line can use different versions.  Depends on your setup and hosting but if you describe more we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I can't log back into my account here (having a bad day all around) but I have CiviCRM 4.2.4

Comment: 4.2.4 is ancient - as Jon G says, you have the opposite problem.  Try going back to PHP5.6

Comment: Aidan - could I also update Civi to the latest version to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM 4.2.4 is a very old version - it's from 2012.  It's not compatible with newer versions of PHP - I'd be surprised if it worked with PHP 5.6, let alone 7+.  You can downgrade PHP or upgrade CiviCRM - but since you're upgrading from such an old version, be sure to a) take a backup of the database before beginning, b) upgrade a few versions at a time (I'd go to the last version of 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7 before going to 5.18), c) if you DO have to restore the database, be sure to delete the existing database before restoring the backup.